# How to tailor my result to rank rows on a yearly basis

Tags: sql-server, ranking

[image: Expected :]

[image: Actual]

How to tailor my result to rank rows on a yearly basis
Here, I need to retrieve rows for every year ordering from most recent to past and rank them based on batting Average. 
eg: fOR YEAR 2017 - RANKS 1, 2, 3, 
FOLLOWED BY  YEAR 2016 - RANKS 1, 2, 3,

Comment: can you please post the query as text ? We prefer text rather than image :)

Comment: add `PARTITION BY` to the `dense_rank()`

Comment: It would be nice if you posted the entire question as text. Your initial "requirement" is an image as well. In truth, this looks like a homework question. Homework is meant to be completed by the person who had it assigned, not strangers on the internet. Have you tried to solve the problem yourself? Of not, I suggest doing so first. If you *then* get stuck, then post your question showing your attempt(s) and the problems you had. Don't forget, as well, your tutor is there to help you; so if you're having trouble you can always ask them. You won't learn anything by having the work done for you.